# How to merge 2 adjacent edges into one edge in NetworkX

Tags: networkx

e.g. I have one graph with 3 nodes: a,b,c and 2 edges (a,b), (b,c). Now I'd like remove node b and merge edges (a,b),(b,c) into one edge (a,c), is there any api in networkx for this kind of graph manipulation? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`networkx.contracted_nodes`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.minors.contracted_nodes.html) to generate a new graph with `b` merged into `a`:

```py
G = nx.from_edgelist([('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c')])

H = nx.contracted_nodes(G, 'a', 'b', self_loops=False)
```

Or using [`contracted_edge`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.minors.contracted_edge.html#networkx.algorithms.minors.contracted_edge):

```py
H = nx.contracted_edge(G, ('a', 'b'), self_loops=False)
```

*NB. this returns a new graph, if you want to update in place, use `copy=False`.*

Before:

[image: networkx graph before merging nodes with contracted_nodes]

After:

[image: networkx graph after mergin nodes with contracted_nodes]